# Phalcon Volt disable specific view

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

**Directory Structure :**

[image: Directory Structure]

```
Class ProductControl extends Controller{
   readAction(){ 
   }
}
```

So, it will be show the volt view in Directory `Product` : `read.volt`, but it still include `index.volt` in root View.

How can i not include the views/`index.volt`, but only include views/product/`read.volt` ?

Answer (score 3):

`$this->view->disableLevel(View::LEVEL_MAIN_LAYOUT);` in your action

Comment: i just found out that its work with 
            $this->view->setMainView("product/read.volt");

can u explain which is better ? my way or your way? thx

Comment: Juri's way is the correct way! You are just using a workaround which actually isn't really the way it is intended to be used. You are just lucky it is giving the correct output. :)